# Script where I check a cell for value < 0 (negative number)

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a scrip that check a cell for < 0 values (negative numbers) but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var days_left = days_left_values[i][0];
if(days_left < 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes numbers stored in spreadsheets are pulled into apps script as strings.  Try this for line 3

```
if(parseFloat(days_left)<0){
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still no luck. If I use the same script for ==0 or any positive numbers then it works just fine.

Comment: Hi.  I just checked the function. Perhaps the issue is somewhere else.  Can you share more of your function.   The following works  to not include the -1.                  var array = [-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
  
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   
    if(array[i]<0){continue;} 
   
   
    Logger.log(array[i]);
  }

Comment: You might also try changing the "numRows - 1" in your first line to "day_left_values.length"

Comment: Thank you, got it working.  Made a typing error getting the range. My original script work.